# React component does not re-render, but render() gets called

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my component.  It renders the first time.  Subsequently, even though render gets called, it does not change the DOM.

Render is getting called at the right times, because I have redux set up and my 'mapStateToProps' seems to work correctly, in that it detects a change in application state, and calls render().

The console log does log the fact that the string has changed.

You would probably like to see more code, but I'm hoping that I'm missing a fundamental concept here that someone can just point out.  I'm not sure how to put my whole project up here. Thanks. Again, render DOES get called, so shouldn't it update the DOM?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class TinyMCETestResultElement extends Component {
  render (){
    console.log ("this.props.form0DataToDisplay " + this.props.form0DataToDisplay)// logs a changed string, as expected
    return (
      <div>
        <div>results: {this.props.form0DataToDisplay}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  //whatever gets returned will show up as props inside of
  return{
     form0DataToDisplay: state.tinyMceTestData
   }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, null)(TinyMCETestResultElement )
```

Comment: Where is your component? I don't see the code.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, fixed.

Comment: Try to implement another lifecycle methods described here, and run console.log in this methods.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: @dt1000 Did you find a solution for this weird issue ?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` in render block is the reason of such components behaviour.
React will rerender component only in case of it's state or props was changed. There is no updated props/state in your code sample, so component rendered only ones.

You can create variable in store for random value and update it with `Math.random()` into reducer. Then use it in your component as props and all wonna be ok.

Comment: Good point, it was a bad test. I have edited the code and the question please re-read, if you have time.  The problem still remains. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because Redux's connected component is implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` for you, and it sees that your props don't change. As a result it won't update that component for you.

You can read about it here:

### Redux Docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

*"...we suggest instead generating container components with the React Redux library’s connect() function, which provides many useful optimizations to prevent unnecessary re-renders. (One result of this is that you shouldn’t have to worry about the React performance suggestion of implementing shouldComponentUpdate yourself.)"*

### Twitter: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/719723707124604928

A quick fix would probably be to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to always return true, overriding Redux's implementation. Or better, having your props change everytime you get a new random number.

Comment: Good point, it was a bad test. I have edited the code and the question please re-read, if you have time.  The problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned that I was using a tiny mce component as the source of the change in state.  If anyone comes across this question, there seemed to be an issue with loading that component, which could be fixed by re-rendering after initial load. I added this code to the tiny mce component to fix it.  Timer may not be necessary.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.forceUpdate();
    }, 1)
  }
```

Comment: please mark this as answer so that other users do not have to scroll down to all other answers to fid the appropriate solution.